# The procedure entry point could not be located in wbemcomn.dll, when using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling

I've written a .bat file that uses `tasklist`. It works fine on most PCs however when I tested it on my relatives computer, they recieved the above error. As far as I am aware, this is a system specific error not related to my coding, however it would be helpful if somebody could confirm or correct me on this.

My main concern is that this batch file is utilised by an application that is soon to be available to consumers. The application writes the file to a temporary location, executes it and then closes the program (the .bat is like a clean up script), so if this error does appear the main application will be closed also. Firstly, is there a way to handle this and prevent that nasty error from popping up - possibly re-openinug the application if an error does occur. Secondly, in terms of usability and user experience how much of an issue is this; the fact that the batch file was deployed means that the user quit the program anyway?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I don't believe that it is related to the code as the error only occurs on one out of many of the machines I have tested it on. However here is a slightly adapted portion of the code that produces the error just in case it is relavant:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set checks=0

call :main

:main
tasklist /nh /fi "PID eq 123456">nul 
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" (
echo %checks%
set /a checks+=1
if "%checks%" == "100" (
echo "Error"
exit /b 1
)
goto :main 
) || (
goto :function
)
```

Comment: You know, asking about code and not providing the code is like ringing your doctor and saying "Look at this rash, what is it?" :)

Comment: @foxidrive I'm not really asking about code as though, I'm asking about an error which I know occurs when I run tasklist on this specific machine, so it could be any batch file which uses `tasklist`.

Comment: I doubt that it is tasklist at all but without seeing your code it is impossible to know. Your script has another issue most likely, or there is a fundamental flaw in your install of Windows.  See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f7c2ef4-d36c-47db-896a-b92e09662b47/wbemcomndll-errors-are-preventing-me-from-installing-or-running-many-programs?forum=smallbusinessserver

Comment: I will upload an adaptation of the portion of my code which causes the error, however I do believe that there is a fundamental flaw in my relatives operating system as it works fine on my machines - as stated in my original question. That link seems to correspond with what I have found so far, but this does not actually answer my original question(s).

Comment: @foxidrive Well, actually if you look at the output, the value of `%checks` does increment on each loop. The batch script works FINE, apart from on one specific machine but you are totally missing the point of my question. I know I can't avoid this error, but I'm asking if there is any way I can handle it and prevent that nasty error appearing?!

Comment: If it happens on one PC and not others, it's not a programming related question.  It's a flaw in the Windows installation.  Maybe SuperUser is a better place to get help on this issue.

Comment: The reason I posted here is because I didn't know whether there was some code I could use to 'handle' the error in the event of the batch file being run on a corrupt installation. I'm pretty certain I know what caused this error and how to fix it now, so I don't see much point in using SuperUser